# What is the accreditation status of the Jean Grey School for Higher Education?

Tags: marvel, wolverine-and-the-x-men

Sparked from the question ["What is the status of the Xavier Institute for Higher Learning's accreditation?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/what-is-the-status-of-the-xavier-institute-for-higher-learnings-accreditation), which specifically mentiones this is another matter.

That said, given that it's a new school, what is the accreditation status of Wolverine's new school?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After [Schism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men#2010s), Wolverine goes back to Salem to establish a new school which he names "The Jean Grey School for Higher Learning".

For this event (and the launch of the new titles after "Schism"), Marvel had a [syllabus and staff chart drawn up for the school](http://nerdapproved.com/approved-products/the-jean-grey-school-for-higher-learning-staff-chart-and-syllabus/):

[image: Jean Grey School of Higher Learning syllabus]

[image: Jean Grey School of Higher Learning staff chart]

These were included in the back of the first title of the new series ["Wolverine & The X-Men"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_and_the_X-Men_%28comics%29).

Issue one deals with, among other things, [Wolverine's attempt to get the school accredited by the New York State Board of Regents](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_&_the_X-Men_Vol_1_1).

This continues through [issue three](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_&_the_X-Men_Vol_1_3) (encompassing an arc dealing with an attack on Wolverine's new school by the newly reformed [Hellfire Club](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellfire_Club_%28comics%29), led by [Kade Kilgore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellfire_Club_%28comics%29#The_Seventh_Inner_Circle)).

The attack is ultimately repelled along with the memories of the inspectors from the New York State Board of Regents being wiped clean for the preceding 24 hours.  That, combined with a good amount of charm applied by [the Beast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_%28comics%29) leads to the school being accredited.